# SAS create equally spaced bins

Tags: sas, bins

I am one variable and the max and min of the variable. How can I create equally spaced 10 bins from min to max? I feel proc rank won't work because I want equally spaced. For example, min=1, max =100, then if a number is 92, then it falls into bin 9, if it is 72, then it falls into bin 7.

Comment: You want a histogram, it sounds like?  What does "Create" mean?

Comment: Equally spaced in terms of the number in each bin or the size of each bin? Assuming its the size, you first need the min/max, divide that by 10 to get the size of each bin and then allocate those to groups.

Comment: Are min and max of the values present or of the expected/allowed values.  For data values present, consider 13,15,19. min=13 and max=19.  Do you want 10 bins covering 13 to 19 ?  If so, try `Proc RANK GROUPS=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do.  Based on what you've posted you can do the following:

```
1) create new variable = ((old variable - min)/ (max value - min)) * 100
   that creates a variable that is now between 0 and 100

2) bin into 10 bins: int(new variable / 10)  will give you the bin number
```

if this is what you are looking for post a sample data set and I can supply additional code.